# My header view in UITableView is not added to the UIView Hierarchy

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview-hierarchy, debugview

Using `UITableView` and `NSFetchedResultsController` I refresh and display the content of my table. At some point I hava a screen without header view. It should be instead of the space between cells.

[image]

When I debug View hierarchy I have the following info. Selected cell in **UI View hierarchy** is appriopriate to the selected cell in **Debug View Hierarchy**.
[image]

[image]

To create a header view I use following method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let workday = workDayObjectForSection(section)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(PBOUserWorkDayCellIdentifier) as! PBOUserWorkDayTableViewCell
    cell.configureCellWithWorkDay(workday)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Why do you put `ReusableCell` to header? It is the reason

Comment: Really? I have been suggested to use table view cell as a header view in another question on stack overflow.

Comment: You may use same view, but you shouldn't get it from `tableView` as reusable cell, i.e. you should create it every time from scratch

Comment: @Azat So I create `UIView` in XIB file with my custom class and then I reuse my view, right? Why is it wrong to reuse cells from table view as a header view?

Comment: You may store in your own array pointers to your headers, and return them instead of creating again, but do not use cells from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, because `tableView` manages them itself internally and may hide/move/whatever when it is appropriate

Comment: And please show us the answer where it is suggested to return dequeued cell as header. We should downvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't get `view` for `tableView` header using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html):

> If a cell object is reusable you assign it a reuse identifier (an arbitrary string) in the storyboard. At runtime, the table view stores cell objects in an internal queue. When the table view asks the data source to configure a cell object for display, the data source can access the queued object by sending a dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: message to the table view, passing in a reuse identifier

That means when you return header as reuse cell, `tableView` might take it do display in another place as cell. Note that behavior of header is different than cell, it stays at the top while section is visible.

However, you may use same view for header but create it from `xib`, `storyboard` etc every time and do not assign any reuse identifier. And if you looking for some optimization, you can store them in some array and return cached values. But I would like to recommend not to use subclasses of `UITableViewCell` as table header views